# parseDOM error in Firefox 45.0

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom

I use the folowing code to convert HTML page into DOM object

```
var htmlPage = '<img id="img1" src="myImage.jpg" /> ';
var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlPage, "text/html");
```

and then I can use the doc object to access any html component like this

```
doc.img1
```

This morning I upgraded my firefox to version 45.0 (latest version), but suddenly the above code stopped working!!
and I start to get the error

```
doc.img1 is undefined
```

is there anything wrong? or did mozilla changed the way the parse the HTML into DOM... or is it a bug?

Comment: var parser = new DOMParser();

Comment: Seems that Firefox no longer lets you select elements by ID as properties of the `document` object. The `img` is available from the `doc.images` collection, either by index or by ID. It's also in the document's `body`, so you can do `doc.body.firstElementChild`.